# I need to export large files to PDF using Laravel

Tags: laravel, wkhtmltopdf, phpwkhtmltopdf

I am trying to export to PDF from HTML, using wkhtmlpdf with laravel, but throws an error because of the external links.
I am using the barryvdh/laravel-snappy wrapper but an error is thrown because of the external files, bootstrap (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css, and image files hosted on cloudinary).
A part of the error shown is:

Error: Failed to load https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css, with network status code 3 and http status code 0 - Host not found

I have seen articles that suggests using http instead of https, but that still didn't work

Comment: For external link as CSS, I used something like this :
`<link href="file:///{!! resource_path('assets/css/'); !!}print.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Thanks, but what I am trying to say is in a case where I want to load the file from an external source like a cdn or something